Spring initializr, which Java version when using Kotlin?
I want to start with Spring boot and Kotlin. Now I am wondering, which Java version should one choose? How does it even matter when using Kotlin?
https://start.spring.io/ offers Java 17, 21, 23 as options.

that would depend on the version of Kotlin. Some require a higher JVM version than others.

but there is no kotlin version option, only choice between java and kotlin.

you choose the kotlin version based on the java version you have chosen.

@AlexT Not possible, there is only a Java version one can select, no Kotlin version number. See https://start.spring.io/

yes, and each Java version implicitly comes with a specific Kotlin version

As specified here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/faq.html#which-versions-of-jvm-does-kotlin-target by default the compiler generates Java 8 bytecode from your code.
That's why it doesn't really matter which version you choose until it's not under 1.8.
My guess for the choice between 17, 21 and 23 is that it's related to Spring 3 and it dependencies more than to Kotlin itself.
(here is another SO question which could help: Which versions of Kotlin are compatible with which versions of Java?)
